# Some Model with ID "xx" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin

I can't access the change page with an ID yet it exists in the DB, in a certain Django account, but I can do access it on the admin account. I checked all the permissions and they seem okay, only that am getting this error :

[image]

But when I navigate this URL (same URL) on admin below it works very well:

```
http://localhost:8000/en/admin/accounts/cooperationemployee/25/change/
```

So am wondering what causes this issue yet the `Id` exists in the DB.

Model for **CooperationEmployee** :

```
class CooperationEmployee(models.Model):
    cooperation_employee_id = models.CharField(
    _('Cooperation Employee ID'), max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    international_prefix = CountryField(
        _('International prefix'), null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(_('Telephone Nr'), max_length=20)
    branch = models.CharField(
        _('Relevant branch'), max_length=50, blank=True, 

null=True)
email_user = models.OneToOneField(
        EmailUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='cooperation_employee_profile',
        verbose_name=_('Email user'))
```

My DB shows this, the ID is available (Postgres) :

[image]

The admin page for CooperationEmployee has this :

```
def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        """Permissions to change account settings."""
        if request.user.role == ROLE_COOPERATION_EMPLOYEE:
            return True
        return False
```

The role **ROLE_COOPERATION_EMPLOYEE** is for the model above.

**EDIT :**

This is the **queryset** :

```
user_id = EmailUser.objects.get(
            id=request.user.id).cooperation_employee_profile.id
```

The model for **EmailUser** :

```
class EmailUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), max_length=64)
    role = models.CharField(
        _('Role'), max_length=2, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

So, the complete routing code is as below :

```
class CooperationPartnerGenericChangeView(ListAPIView):

  
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       
        
        url = 'adminsite:accounts_cooperationemployee_change'
        user_id = EmailUser.objects.get(
            id=request.user.id).cooperation_employee_profile.id

        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse(url, kwargs={'object_id': user_id}) + '?edit=1')
```

note:

This is a reverse url `adminsite:accounts_cooperationemployee_change`. for `http://localhost:8000/en/admin/accounts/cooperationemployee/25/change/`

Comment: Perhaps a filtered queryset is used where you get the error. Can't tell because you have not shared many details about the view where the error happens.

Comment: @4140tm, the queryset returns 25, even when I explictly add it there, it should route, but it doesn't, let add the querysets and you see.

Comment: @4140tm, I have added more code to see what is really happening, hope it makes sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I'd like to address, which do not fit in a comment:

1. You are using `list` view of one model to redirect to a change view of the same model using id from another model. That's everything the list view does, according to that snippet.
2. That queryset is not where the error happens. It also seems redundant - you are using the id of current user to get `EmailUser` by id and then pass the returned object's id to the other view. You could just pass `request.user.id`. But how can you be sure that the ids of `EmailUser` and `CooperationEmployee` objects would match?
3. The error seems to occur in the view where you redirect to and there is the relevant queryset you need to check.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I had a wrong queryset, for the `EmailUser`, I edited it.  So the question is , how to  debug this error in the template

Comment: In the ListAPIView , I was only redirecting :

`HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse(url, kwargs={'object_id': user_id}) + '?edit=1')`

Would this be an issue?

Comment: I see the edit and it's  bit more clear now. BTW, you could use `cooperation_employee_profile_id` instead of `cooperation_employee_profile.id` in this case, to do one fewer db queries. I'm not sure what you mean by debugging in the template though. This is something you have to debug in python - that's where the code is executed. The template is at the end of the process and receives computed values

Comment: Regarding the list view - it's a list view, typically used to list items. If you are going to limit it to a single item, better use [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview). Since it's only redirecting, you could also use a [`RedirectView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview). And since you know that this url would redirect, why not send the user directly to the end url? Nothing else seems to be happening in between.

Comment: Ok thanks for the additional Views let test them out. But what I do is, I get the URL generated and pass it to an anchor tag.